# Click a link from a keyup event in input field

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpages

I have a search input field and want to activate the search when the user presses Enter after typing in their search phrase. I also have a link control that has the SSJS to redirect to another XPage (and would add some paramters that I get using SSJS so just using CSJS to open another page is not an option).  This works great in Chrome but in Firefox does nothing.  Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" style="width:142.0px">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onkeyup"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[if (typeof thisEvent == 'undefined' &&     window.event) { thisEvent = window.event; }
if (thisEvent.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER)
{
dojo.byId("#{id:searchButton}").click();
thisEvent.preventDefault();
}]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:inputText>
<xp:link
    escape="true"
    text="Search"
    id="searchButton">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
        disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#    {javascript:context.redirectToPage("search.xsp");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link></xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar functionality that works as expected in Firefox. The difference is that I use onkeypress instead of onkeyup:

```
<xp:inputText id="searchName" value="#{viewScope.searchName}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            if (typeof thisEvent == 'undefined' && window.event) { thisEvent = window.event; }
            if (thisEvent.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER)
            {
                dojo.byId("#{id:searchButton}").click();
                thisEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: thanks, that does seem to work, strange, I was getting to the line before the .click when I had some debug code that outputted to the browser console. I will have to try this in the real application.

Comment: Similarly, in the Todo sample app in the ExtLib and Bluemix boilerplate, in the login dropdown on the simpleLayout custom control, the input fields capture the enter key and perform the login when it is pressed. They use onkeypress as Per suggests and seem to work fine on Chrome/Firefox